# Linux - Splitting a backup into two steps

Tags: linux, backup, bash, tar, archive

I create a tarball using `tar zcf arhive.tar.gz dir/` and this works ok. Now I wanted to split this into two simple archives, one only for images, the other -- for everything else.

It seems that there's not a trivial and clean way to do this. For `tar` I can only exclude files, which is unreasonable to exclude every extension except gif, jpg, and png.

To include I have to use `find` with either -`exec` or `| xargs`. This kinda works, but breaks if the filenames have spaces or special characters (apostrophes, quotation marks). So now I have to pipe all the filenames into, say, `awk` and escape them manually?

What am I missing? Why is this so complicated?

I just wanted `tar zcf archive-images.tar.gz dir/ --match-only=*.png`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 tar...`  these two options exist in order to deal with filenames with spaces.

Comment: This is not a good idea. You can only pass so many arguments to a process (and when taring up an entire filesystem, isnt too unlikely). The better way is to pipe directly to tar with the `--null --files-from` arguments.